# Using par function in R

Tags: r

I get this when I try to use the `par` function in R.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2)) 
Error in .getClassFromCache(Class, where) : 
  argument "Class" is missing, with no default
```

This happens any time I try use the `par` function, not just in this case.

What's going on and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Does the problem persist if you restart R without loading a saved workspace?

Comment: And to you know "how" to remove the typically invisible `.Rdata` workspace? It appears that someone , you? , may have implemented a plotting S4 function incorrectly.

Comment: Yes it did persist so needed to use rm(par). Easy fix but I hadn't even thought of doing that so thanks!